# Font looks different in same UILabel in one of my iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, uilabel

As attached image, in Label2 I assigned Helvetica 15 font size from XIB. But it shows different font for *"**Share stories and ideas.**" and "**Send live on or off the app.**" texts in same label.*
Why is this happening? why it shows different font size in same label?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and double checked with Photoshop and except for very minor kerning differences the "Share stories and ideas" part is identical in both cases. As for the "Send love on or off..." the font size there is also basically identical, compare the "S" or "e" for example.

Kerning is something that the font render does automatically, see this wikipedia article for more information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Kerning

The "Send love on or off" part visually looks sparser, but that is just an effect from for short words in a row using the wide character "o". Perhaps that is what you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got little idea for Kerning. But not sure how Kerning applies in iOS. I an using one UILabel and just assigned the text and font size, but it looks different in same UILabel.

Comment: @Tushar I see that you changed the attached image in the question. However, even with this image there is _no_ change in font size between the first and second part. I checked it again with Photoshop, the "S" in both cases is identical, as are the other common characters.  

If by "font size" you mean that the second part of the string looks sparser or more "stretched out" then see the last paragraph of my answer.